# express Error: Cannot find module '../..'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I'm a beginer with node.js.
I installed node on Ubuntu 12.04 and it works fine for simple simple apps.
I also installed express using:

```
npm install -g express
```

I believe the installation worked fine since I get no errors but right now I want to run one of their apps from the examples (the mvc one) and I get the following error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '../..'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/andreii/Desktop/node/mvc/index.js:2:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
```

Any ideas about how can I solve this problem?
Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: It would be nice if you post the actual example code that gives you that error.

Comment: Hi lanzz, You can find it here: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/mvc

Comment: So, you believe that in order to help _you_, we should make extra effort just to figure out what your problem is? Isn't this a bit arrogant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var express = require('../..');
```

Simply change the first line of your code like this

```
var express = require('express');
```

All well goes fine after that.